# Unreal Engine is running in Ubuntu 16 but I get error when I try to load AirSim in the folder where I cloned Unreal GitHub

Tags: c++, simulation, ubuntu-16.04, unreal-engine4

**Clone** AirSim.git  and .**/setup.sh** worked well but I get error when I run:

```
:~/myAIRSIM/AirSim$ ./build.sh
```

> - git submodule update --init --recursive
> - [[ -d ./llvm-build/output/lib ]]
> - echo 'ERROR: clang++ and libc++ is necessary to compile AirSim and run it in Unreal engine' ERROR: clang++ and libc++ is necessary to
>     compile AirSim and run it in Unreal engine
> - echo 'please run setup.sh first.' please run setup.sh first.
> - exit 1

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/AirSim/blob/master/docs/build_linux.md

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install clang++ and libc++. I assume you are using linux, I think the AirSim is still in Beta phase, it only support certain OS, Windows 10 with VS Studio 2015 works, not VS 2017! And for linux, you have to follow the exact instruction.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes Ubuntu 16, see link in my comment. You are thinking wrong about AirSim,  my question was after following instruction see error. How to install those?